# Query to only display matching elements in two dimensions

Tags: mdx

**Short question:**
Any idea how I can pull the name from one dimension entry and apply it to another as filter?

**Long description:** My cube has has dimensions for manufacturer and seller, and I only need sales for "themselves". The dimensions are loaded from distinct tables in the source but have entries with the exact same name.

```
Manufacturer   Seller
  A              A       *
  A              D
  B              B       *
  C              C       *
  C              A
  C              D
```

A, B and C sell their products themselves, A and C also sell through reseller D. C also sells through A. I'd like to filter for the marked rows only (names matching).

In SQL this would be simple, or the cube might be easily enhanced to flag "own sales", but both options are not available. I need to query the cube "as is".

I tried using STRTOMEMBER and CURRENTMEMBER like so (with NAME and MEMBER_NAME):

```
STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Seller].[Seller].[" + [Dim Producer].[Producer].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME + "]
```

That actually works, syntactically, but CURRENTMEMBER seems to always evaluate to ALL and delivers the (correct) measure value for the ALL element yet not the one for matching name.

I also tried to create a WHERE setting the two names equal

```
[Dim Seller].[Seller].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME = [Dim Producer].[Producer].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME
```

but that is very SQL and not valid in MDX.

The whole query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    NON EMPTY {
        [Measures].[Value]
    } ON COLUMNS
    , NON EMPTY { (
        {
            [Dim Producer].[Producer].[A]
            , [Dim Producer].[Producer].[B]
            , [Dim Producer].[Producer].[C]
        }
        * [Dim Seller].[Seller].[Seller].ALLMEMBERS
// This line needs to be trimmed to same name as producer
    ) } ON ROWS
FROM
    [Cube]
```

The producer list is coming from a config file and string-concatenated to the query and subject to change. Having a second seller list to be kept in sync would be a burden but also (when C sells through A) deliver wrong results.

Any idea how I can pull the name from one dimension entry and apply it to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause might help you:

```
SELECT
    NON EMPTY {
        [Measures].[Value]
    } ON COLUMNS
    , NON EMPTY { 
        {
              [Dim Producer].[Producer].[A]
            , [Dim Producer].[Producer].[B]
            , [Dim Producer].[Producer].[C]
        }
        * [Dim Seller].[Seller].[Seller].ALLMEMBERS
    } 
HAVING 
    [Dim Seller].[Seller].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_NAME = 
            [Dim Producer].[Producer].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_NAME
ON ROWS
FROM
    [Cube]
```

Comment: This solution looks less complex, is shorter and works fine. I prefer it over the one given before.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `GENERATE` function to do the job for you.

```
with set Producers as
{[Dim Producer].[Producer].[A]
,[Dim Producer].[Producer].[B]
,[Dim Producer].[Producer].[C]}

set Sellers as
[Dim Seller].[Seller].members

//For every producer, get the seller who shares the same name.
set ProducersHavingSameNameAsSellers as
GENERATE(Producers, GENERATE(Sellers, filter
                                                (Sellers, 
                                                    [Dim Seller].[Seller].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_NAME = 
                                                    [Dim Producer].[Producer].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_NAME
                                                )
                            )
        )

SELECT
NON EMPTY [Measures].[Value] ON COLUMNS,
ProducersHavingSameNameAsSellers ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

Comment: Please up vote the answer/Mark it as an answer if it helped you

Comment: No, sorry, I need to take back my previous success comment. It does not work correct. The combinations where a seller ist also a manufacturer come through (5th line of the original question example). I think (hope) this is easy to fix and the general approach is correct.

Comment: Now you got me confused! I thought it was about sellers and producers! My answer gives you sellers who are also producers. What exactly do you want?

Comment: Manufacturers was just another word for Producers, sorry for that, it is the same dimension. I need to investigate a little more, the numbers (measures) seem correct. I might have introduced a bug (unwanted crossjoin) myself on the real query while the generate-part from you seems ok! Upvote and answer as I am pretty sure I got it now!